# Oracle SQL Package with cursor selects table from same schema as package but "table or view does not exist" - SQL standalone runs correctly

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a massive package that I am working with. Inside that package is a cursor with a select clause - simple select but returns a lot of columns.

Relevant info: this is done via a script. Running in sqlplus with a user different from the schema in question.

```
Signed in user = SignedInUser
Package Schema = PackageSchema
```

```
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = PackageSchema;
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;

SET SQLBLANKLINES ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE New_Package authid CURRENT_USER AS
...

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY New_Package AS
....
CURSOR new_curser
       (
       needed_id  PackageSchema.V_Existing_View.id%TYPE
       )
IS
SELECT     column1,
           column2,
           ...
FROM       PackageSchema.V_Existing_View
WHERE      id = needed_id;
```

The package and the view it's pulling from are in the same schema. However, I'm getting "table or view doesn't exist" for this.

Everything I've looked up says this is a permissions issue. My users are created with a GRANT ALL PRIVS on the USER. I've had no other clashes in being able to reach any other tables.

When I take just the sql statement into sqlplus and run it directly, it runs without issue.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have `authid CURRENT_USER` so it appears the user you are connecting as to execute the package procedure/function does not have privileges on the table; it doesn't matter that the package owner does with that `authid`. You said "My users are created with a GRANT ALL PRIVS" - but does that include the connecting user? Are you granting privileges directly, or via a role? (And - why would you do that - you should grant the minimum privs actually necessary for each user?)

Comment: Please do not set `_oracle_script`. That is to be used internally by Oracle only or when directed to do so by support. Oracle did not intend it to be used by customers.

Comment: This is a local development seed against an oracle docker. It's just meant to house data for our local testing. Yes, the user I'm signed in with is one of the seeded users from the seed. This seed is a volume that is attached to the opt/oracle/script/setup folder in docker.

Comment: There are 72 scripts being seeded. This is script number 71. The script is one of a handful of files that have multiple thousands of lines (and yes, that is one package). This is not my work or my doing, just something I have to copy locally to get as reliable a test environment as possible to match the "real" database that we're not allowed to call out to directly.

Comment: Grant:

CREATE USER PackageSchema IDENTIFIED BY "PackageSchema" ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO PackageSchema;
GRANT RESOURCE TO PackageSchema;

Comment: I'm (mostly) asking about the *executing* user, SignedInUser - what privileges does that have on the table?

Comment: It is the same. It is one of the user seeded in the way I put above. I am not adding any further permissions than those 3 statements.